# How to unit test the value of a control once a wpf form has loaded in Visual Studio?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

Currently I'm testing visually by running the app and looking at the form. How can I automate this with Visual Studio ?

Comment: hope this ends with printscreening and visual diff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate you can use the Coded UI feature:

- [Creating Automated Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380755.aspx)

and here's a walk through with WPF:

- [Walkthrough: Creating, Editing and Maintaining a Coded UI Test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff977233.aspx)